# Haskell - Is there a way to limit the execution time for a given function?

Tags: haskell

Suppose I have a function in Haskell which may not always terminate. Is there a way to make the program halt itself if it's taking too long to compute?

Example:

```hs
import qualified Data.Map as Map

walkmap :: Int -> Map.Map Int Int -> Int
walkmap x m = case Map.lookup x m of
  Nothing -> x
  Just y -> walkmap y m

main :: IO ()
main = do
  let ma = Map.fromList [(0,1), (1,2)]
  let mb = Map.fromList [(0,1), (1,0)]
  print $ walkmap 0 ma
  print $ walkmap 0 mb
```

`walkmap ma 0` should return 2 right away, but `walkmap mb 0` would loop forever. I know it's impossible to know for sure if the function would halt or not, what I'd like to know is if there's a way to set a time limit (say, 10 seconds) for that computation.

Comment: Better limit the recursion depth

Comment: [**`timeout`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/System-Timeout.html#v:timeout)?

Comment: both approaches would suit me, I didn't think about just limiting recursion :p

Comment: You could also implement a helper that keeps track of the keys used in a given evaluation. If you ever see a key for the second time, you can return immediately. (Depending on the size of your map, this could be more reliable than simply using a timeout or hard-coded recursion limit, which could abort prematurely on a heavily loaded machine.)

Comment: The recursion limit doesn't have to be hard-coded. If you use the size of the map as your limit, you will find all valid paths but still abort on all loops, with only a small constant memory overhead rather than an entire Map.

Comment: What should the behavior be when it exceeds the limit? Program termination, or an error that can be handled?

Comment: @KevinP.Barry it could be any of those, or even an "error value", like `Nothing`, as `timeout` does.

Comment: Since such issues can also result in memory exhaustion, you might consider relying on the OS to limit resource consumption, e.g., `ulimit` in Linux. (Unless you're creating some sort of daemon.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer to the question as asked looks like this:

```
timeout (10*1000000) (evaluate (walkmap 0 mb)) >>= print
```

But the answer to the "avoid cycles in a lookup" question that's behind it is Brent's remarkable [tortoise and hare algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_detection#Brent%27s_algorithm). (Beware! I have only tested this code on your exact two test cases. There could be bugs lurking in it. You should read about the algorithm behind the link and code review (or re-implement) it yourself.)

```
walkmap :: Ord a => a -> Map.Map a a -> Maybe a
walkmap a m = case Map.lookup a m of
    Nothing -> Just a
    Just a' -> go a a' (iterate (2*) 1)
    where
    -- p for pause
    go a a' ps | a == a' = Nothing
    go a a' (p:ps) = case Map.lookup a' m of
        Nothing -> Just a'
        Just a''
            | p == 0 -> go a' a'' ps
            | otherwise -> go a a'' (p-1:ps)
```